# Issues with foreach in php to call a function

Tags: php, function, prestashop

In the following code, the function `parseImages` is not implemented.

Can someone help me to call the function `parseImages` in the `foreach`:

```
foreach ($listFeatured as &z$product) {
    $product['description'] = substr(trim(strip_tags($product['description_short'])), 0, $maxDesc);
    $product['price'] = Tools::displayPrice($product['price']);
    $product = $this->parseImages($product, $params);
    $product = $this->generateImages($product, $params);
} 


function parseImages($product, $params) {
    global $link;
    $isRenderedMainImage = $params->get("cre_main_size", 0);

    if (_PS_VERSION_ <= "1.5.0.17") {
        $mainImageSize = $params->get("main_img_size", 'thickbox');
    } else {
        $mainImageSize = $params->get("main_img_size",   'thickbox_default');
    }

    if ($isRenderedMainImage) {
        if ((int) Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS') == 1) {
            $product["mainImge"] = $this->getImageLink($product["link_rewrite"], $product["id_image"]);
        } else {
            $product["mainImge"] = $link->getImageLink($product["link_rewrite"], $product["id_image"]);
        }
    } else {
        $product["mainImge"] = $link->getImageLink($product["link_rewrite"], $product["id_image"], $mainImageSize);
    }

    $product["thumbImge"] = $product["mainImge"];

    return $product;
}
```

This is a piece of a module of Prestashop and I want to use it twice.
If solved I will share the solution to all Prestashop users.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't understand your question since you have implemented the function and you allready are calling it within the loop...?

Comment: Do not call it as a object metod ($this->parseImages) but as a function: parseImages(); This is unless it is actually a class method. We need more code to know that.

Answer (score 0):

You're using as an object method `$this->parseImages()` but you defined it as a function:

```
function parseImages($product, $params) {
    [...]
}
```

You can keep this function like this and use `parseImages()` without the `$this->` or if you're inside a class change your function declaration to this:

```
public function parseImages($product, $params) {
    [...]
}
```

You should read some [documentation about OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)